# Missing Blender Prefs folder on other Mac user account

Tags: customization, osx

Today I decided to make Blender available to another user account on my Mac.

(Blender 2.92, macOS Mojave 10.14.6)

The first obstacle was a permissions issue, that persisted no matter what, to the extent that I had to re-download Blender while logged in as that user, and copy the .app file into `Applications` and authorize it as Admin. (Had to make sure the file names were different, of course.)

But even after that, there is no Blender Prefs folder for that user.

When I go to `~/Library/Application Support/Blender/` on my admin account, of course I see Blender's preference data.

But on the other account (which can launch Blender, only with default settings) there is no `Blender` folder in Application Support. See screenshot:

[image]

What's going on here? And how do I copy my Blender preference data over for that other user?

(I say "copy" rather than "sync" or "share" because I don't want changes they make to their prefs to affect mine.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Never mind.

I thought that a `Blender` folder automatically got created upon the first launch of Blender under that account.

But it turns out that you need to save some preferences of some sort in order for that folder to be created. Once you do that the folder appears, and then just swap out the `2.92` folder for the one containing the preferences your desire to copy over.

Or you could just create the `~/Library/Application Support/Blender/` folder yourself. There is no need to rely on the app to do it.

Pretty simple stuff. My mistake was just based on the flawed assumption that it gets created on first launch. But it's actually on first prefs save.

Please move along, nothing to see here...